# Why doesn't Ctrl + F5 work in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, xubuntu

I'm using Xubuntu 11.04, and with a Windows XP in my VirtualBox. Both have latest Firefox 4 installed. But inside my Ubuntu, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> never works, and because I don't know what else I could do to force refreshing a page, I have to copy the link and paste them into my Windows XP to get the newest results.

Is there a way that I could solve this?

Thank you very much if this problem could get a solution.

**EDIT:** Even though <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> doesn't work, I just found it can also be triggered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> too.

Full shortcuts reference [here](http://www.mouserunner.com/FF_Shortcuts1Printable.html).

Comment: This problem occurs because Xubuntu uses Ctrl+F5 to switch into fifth workspace (if you don't have as much workspaces, then simply nothing happens), in fact whole F1-F12 range is reserved. There are **two** possible solutions: redefine (clear) shorcut in Xubuntu (via Settings→Settings Manager→Window Manager→Keyboard) or as proposed earlier use alternative i.e. Ctrl+Shift+R.

Comment: This answer was awesome:
This problem occurs because Xubuntu uses Ctrl+F5 to switch into fifth workspace (if you don't have as much workspaces, then simply nothing happens), in fact whole F1-F12 range is reserved. There are two possible solutions: redefine (clear) shorcut in Xubuntu (via Settings→Settings Manager→Window Manager→Keyboard) or as proposed earlier use alternative i.e. Ctrl+Shift+R. – Grzegorz Szpetkowski Thanks Grzegorz. Turned out to be my exact problem. (Just switched to xfce desktop from MATE to facilitate better response on my VM).

Answer (score 33):

<sub>Moving the [comment from Grzegorz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48475/why-doesnt-ctrl-f5-work-in-firefox/179707#comment142676_48475) into a Community-wiki answer.</sub>

This problem occurs because Xubuntu uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to switch into fifth workspace (if you don't have as much workspaces, then simply nothing happens), in fact whole <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> range is reserved.

There are two possible solutions:

- Redefine (clear) shorcut in Xubuntu (via Settings→Settings Manager→Window Manager→Keyboard) or
- Use alternative i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: i'm using linux lite 4.4 based on ubuntu 18.04. this tweak works there too.

Comment: Had the same problem using Lubuntu 20.04 with LXQT. The solution is largely the same. I truly don't remember this happening with my old Lbuntu setups with plain LXDE.

Answer (score 5):

You must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to overwrite the cache in Xubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but dosn't <kbd>F5</kbd> do the trick? Also you could check if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> is allready used as a gnome shortcut.

Comment: CTRL+F5 doesn't use cached files.

Comment: there are only several shortcuts in my system and none of them are CTRL+F5, is there a way to set firefox's shortcuts?