# Ctrl+F4 doesn't work in KDE for Firefox / Chrome / Chromium

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys, google-chrome, kde, chromium

I observed that the shortcut for closing a tab in Firefox/Chrome/Chromium (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>) doesn't work on KDE. It seems it is being intercepted by KWin.

Is there any fix or workaround for this problem?

Comment: Strange, I always used ctrl+W to close tabs. Both work perfectly for me though (although I'm using Gnome at the moment).

Comment: @KIAaze: Thanks for the comment. This solved my problem. Ctrl+W is a lot easier than pressing Ctrl+F4. I'm using Linux Mint 15.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The reason <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> doesn't work in KDE is because KWin uses the same keyboard shortcut for switching between workspaces. If you would really want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>, you might want to consider editing the KWin keyboard settings.

To do that, open *System Settings* and go to *Shortcuts and Gestures*.

[image: System settings]

Then navigate to *Global Keyboard Shortcuts* and choose *Kwin* from the KDE component dropdown.

[image: Kwin]

Scroll down all the way until you see *Switch to Desktop 4* option. Click on the shortcut and choose *Custom* and either select a different shortcut or leave it as empty.

[image: Removing the shortcut]

You should now be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> to close tabs in Firefox.

---

Related:

- Xubuntu: [Why doesn't Ctrl + F5 work in Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48475/why-doesnt-ctrl-f5-work-in-firefox/179707#179707)

Comment: If you don't want to do all this then just use **Ctrl+W** instead. It works perfectly in Linux Mint 15.

Answer (score 1):

In Xubuntu, keyboard shortcut settings can be find in this path: `Settings→Settings Manager→Window Manager→Keyboard`

[image]